# SailsJS: how to access the res.render function from anywhere

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I just need to use the res.render function at some places but it is not passed to the callback I am using. Isn't there somewhere a global version of the render function or is there another way to access this?

Answer (score 3):

In Sails v0.10.4 there is

```
sails.renderView(viewPath, options, callback);
```

Also, when rendering emails, you probably don't need to use a layout. So before calling `sails.renderView`, add

```
options.layout = false;
```

Comment: I feel this should be the accepted answer. This solves the problem without the need to assert the OP to rethink intentions.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need it at ***all*** places, really.

`res` is a response object and it makes sense only in controllers, because only controllers deal with request handling and response rendering.

Do you want to use `res.render` from models, services? Maybe it's because you think that all your code is always in **we_have_request_and_user_is_waiting_for_response** state.
Well, It's not true: model methods and services can be called from sails console, or from background workers, or from code, than runs by schedule. In these cases we don't have `res` object at all.

Controllers are place specially designed to contain user actions responding logic. So, you should place that logic in controllers.  [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

Comment: I need to access res.render in the 'afterCreate' method of a model so that I can send an email.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, previous speaker is somewhat right: there is a reason `res` exists only within controllers. For example, what if it's a CLI application, and there's simply no request/ response in HTTP-meaning?

That said, if you just need to render some HTML for one or another purpose, you can always use global Express' renderer, which doesn't require response to be presented: it's accessible via `sails.express.app.render`, see [Express' documentation](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.render) for the method's params.

Comment: This will work in v0.9.x, with the caveat that localization methods won't be available.  But `sails.express` won't be available in future versions of Sails.  However, a global view rendering function may be available in v0.10.